# Is there a way in Intellij IDEA to see the name of the method the current line belongs to?

Tags: intellij-idea

In our code base there are a few very long methods (several pages worth of code). When reading the code, it would sometimes be good to be able to see the name of the method the current line belongs to, without paging up to the beginning of the method. Is this possible in Intellij IDEA? I am using Intellij IDEA 7.0.3.

Comment: Is there a way to see the name without any intervention? Without the Alt+Q?

Answer (score 102, accepted):

You can use **View | Context Info** (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> on Macs). It will display a pop-up on the top of the editor with the current context information (class/method signature).

Comment: Hero status. That's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Mark, this is exactly what I'm looking for? Something like Eclipse's breadcrumbs - http://www.pushing-pixels.org/2008/02/10/breadcrumb-bar-in-eclipse-34-milestone-5.html

Comment: got it from below comment: Settings -> Editor -> General -> Breadcrumbs

Comment: This is a very old answer that no longer applies. Look for "breadcrumbs" in Settings (see other answers for more details).

Comment: Funny I don't see anything when I do View | Context Info.  Just got a new update installed phpstorm 2021.2.  The solution was to go to settings->editor->breadcrumbs and set the placement to Top.  Bottom doesn't seem to display any more but I'm relieved to see the function name somewhere!

Answer (score 77):

#### IntelliJ 2018

This is shown by default at the bottom.

Unfortunately, the method is shown only by name (not including the parameters). If a method is overloaded you won't know for sure where you are.

[image: Method breadcrumbs below code area]

If you want to move it from bottom to top, go to **File** > **Settings...** > **Editor** > **General** > **Breadcrumbs** > check **Top**:

[image: Editor > Breadcrumbs > Show breadcrumbs]

Answer (score 28):

In the structure panel select the "Autoscroll from source" option. 
This way when you place the cursor inside any method the structure panel will show which method you're in.

Comment: Auto scroll does not outline the function name it just scrolls. Better do Alt+Q.

Comment: In Android Studio the method is highlighted with a gray bar, so there this solution works quite nicely.

Comment: @Narek it might have changed recently, "Autoscroll from source" does outline the function on IntelliJ 15 CE

Comment: THIS is what I was looking for. In the `Project` view, the "Autoscroll" options are in the context menu. In `Structure` they are... on the toolbar? So confusing!

Comment: You need to turn on the "Show members" option.

Comment: Not working on v2016.1.3. Opened a defect on this: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-157644

Comment: As @lambart said, confused the heck out of me and wasted so much of my time. Doesn't work and is not on the relevant menu. Dont they do any QA with their releases ?? Even if it works, it may give a ticker-tape feel by constantly scrolling. Will be distracting. Alt+Q is the best option IMO.

Answer (score 23):

Intellij now has support for breadcrumbs. Go to settings > appearance and tick "Show breadcrumbs". In this way you can view class/method name without Alt+Q.

Comment: Just to clarify its Settings -> Editor -> General -> Appearance

Comment: For some reason in android studio this was enabled for all languages but not Java and Kotlin. Go figure!

Answer (score 2):

For some reason (Alt-Q) wasn't consistent in Android Studio for me.  I find (Ctrl-F12) to be pretty satisfactory for this purpose (Navigate|File Structure) though it can be a little laggy in larger files.  And by pressing the hotkey again it will populate the list with all the inherited methods as well.

Answer (score 1):

In Intellij v2023.2.3 go to View -> Tool Windows -> Structure, click the "Options" (3 vertical dots) menu, and toggle on the "Always Select Opened Element". With that setting turned on the method will be highlighted in the Structure Tool Window if the cursor is placed anywhere within that method in the source code editor.